# Getting pre-selected Text in dropdown in EditItemTemplate gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, edititemtemplate

I am not able to get preselected text in dropdown in edit template. Please see my code:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="droplist" runat="server">
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

c# code

```
protected void gvDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList droplist = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("droplist");
                droplist.DataSource = EquipmentBLL.getunitdrop();
                droplist.DataTextField = "UnitName";
                droplist.DataValueField = "UnitID";
                droplist.DataBind();
                droplist.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(" Select Unit ", "0"));
                //droplist.Items.FindByText(unittypetext).Selected = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Can someone tell me what I should do to get preselected dropdown?

regards
Hussain

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: no error i need when i click edit button dropdown should be preslected with database value for that perticular row alongside all preselected row items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're populating the `DropDownList` with options from a datasource.  However, you're not binding it's selected value to anything.

Whatever you are doing to bind the other fields in your `Gridview`, do that for the `DropDownList`'s SelectedValue as well.

Without seeing the rest of your `GridView` markup, I'm thinking something like this should work:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="droplist" runat="server" 
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>' >
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Where "UnitID" above is the name of the field from your GridView's datasource that you want to bind to the SelectedValue of the DropDownList.